# How to test that simple linear model is significant using p-value?

Tags: r, regression

[image]

For the question (d), i get the **p-value =  0.0006529 ＜ α = 0.01**, so it is rejected H0, the answer will be **"the simple linear model is not significant"** ?

```
> x = c(35, 49, 21, 39, 15, 28, 25) #RM'00
> y = c(9, 15, 7, 11, 5, 8, 9) #RM'00
> moneyModel = lm(formula = y ~ x)
> summary(moneyModel)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
      1       2       3       4       5       6       7 
-1.3882  0.9134  0.3102 -0.4449 -0.1048 -0.5390  1.2535 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.14225    1.12645   1.014 0.357100    
x            0.26417    0.03507   7.533 0.000653 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9928 on 5 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.919, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9028 
F-statistic: 56.74 on 1 and 5 DF,  p-value: 0.0006529
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused about the significance test for Linear Regression. We can arrive at a conclusion about the significance in relationship between x and y by testing the null hypothesis,ie. β = 0.

```
> help(summary.lm)#to see the summary
```

As the p-value < 0.001, we reject the null hypothesis that β = 0 (since coefficient not equals 0). You can read about it [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135564/null-hypothesis-for-linear-regression).

Note: The no:of stars near p-value shows strength of its significance.

So there is a significant relationship between the variables in this linear regression model.